# using assertion library "expect" within promise does not work

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js

I am using mocha adapter to test my Ember application. When trying to test assertions within visit, I am getting an error the source of which is the adapter.js file. For eg:

when my test script is :

```
it("should check", function () {

    visit('/somePage').then(function () {
        expect("1").to.be("2");
    });
});
```

I get following error in console:

**Uncaught Error: Error: expected '1' to equal '2'**

UPDATE :
The adapter I am using is : https://github.com/teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter

as in the code example now have :

```
beforeEach(function () {
    visit('/somePage')
});

 it("should check", function () {

    click('button').then(function () {
        expect("1").to.be("2");
    });
});
```

still causes the same issue!

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going wrong with their adapter (you may be better off making an issue on their repo), it seems likely their assessment of whether or not your test is async may be broken. Are you sure you need a special adapter for this? When I'm writing promise based tests I always hang `.then(function(){done()}, done)` on the end and my errors are correctly gathered and reported.

Comment: Yeah it might be the adapter issue, I will report an issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is the thread response I received from teddyzeenny that helped me resolve my issue https://github.com/teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter/issues/6